# How to position a picture from the edge of the paper?

Tags: positioning, pstricks, textpos, pst-abspos

I wrote a package that displays the logo of my company:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{acmelogo}[2022/09/09 ACME Inc. Logo]

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{textpos}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,x11names]{pstricks}

\def\logotext{ACME Inc.\\A world company that manufactures everything}

\newcommand{\logo}[2]{%
    \begin{pspicture}(#1,-#2)
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.88 0.15 0.11}
        \psset{
            unit=0.7pt,
            linestyle=none,
            fillstyle=solid,
            fillcolor=curcolor
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(74, 18)
            \lineto(56, 18)
            \lineto(56, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \curveto(67, 7)(63, 5)(57, 5)
            \curveto(50, 5)(45, 10)(45, 17)
            \curveto(45, 24)(50, 30)(57, 30)
            \curveto(63, 30)(67, 27)(69, 23)
            \lineto(74, 25)
            \curveto(71, 32)(65, 35)(57, 35)
            \curveto(47, 35)(39, 27)(39, 17)
            \curveto(39, 7)(47, 0)(57, 0)
            \curveto(62, 0)(66, 2)(69, 5)
            \lineto(69, 1)
            \lineto(74, 1)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \closepath
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(27, 61)
            \lineto(5, 61)
            \lineto(5, 75)
            \lineto(0, 75)
            \lineto(0, 42)
            \lineto(5, 42)
            \lineto(5, 56)
            \lineto(27, 56)
            \lineto(27, 42)
            \lineto(33, 42)
            \lineto(33, 75)
            \lineto(27, 75)
            \closepath
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}
```

The goal is to use it on the main document:

```
\begin{document}
\logo
% ...
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the position `\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(-1cm, 1.7cm)` isn't absolute to the paper, but to the geometry of the page.

How is it possible to position that logo at an absolute position from the page?

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
\logo[left=1cm,top=1cm]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `tikz` package it is possible to position material using absolute page coordinates, regardless of the geometry used for the text.

It only requires a single line (`\node at ...`) to position the logo image a certain distance from the top and left of the top right corner of the page ( `current page.north west`) while adding the desired logo text to its right (`label`).

The `logotext` command allows you to define and format the logo text while the `logoimg` command does the same for the actual logo.

The position of its center is obtained by `\placelogo{<left>}{<top>}`

[image: a]

Using `\placelogo{<left>}{<top>}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}

% ********************** added<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\logotext}{\sffamily \bfseries \large ACME Inc.\\A world company that manufactures everything}% design the text <<<
\newcommand{\logoimg}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}} % put the real logo

\newcommand{\placelogo}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [label={right:{\parbox{\textwidth}{\logotext}}}]
        {\logoimg};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
% **********************

\begin{document}
    
    \placelogo{2cm}{2cm}    

    Some words
    
\end{document}
```

**Option**  Now using a `pspicture` with the logo and text:

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}   

% ********************** added<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\pssize}\setlength{\pssize}{1cm} % size of the logo image <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\logotextformat}{\sffamily \bfseries \large} % format of the logo text  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\logoimg}[2]{\begin{pspicture}(#1,-#2)      
        \multido{\rA=22.5+45}{8}{
            \rput{\rA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20](0,0)(0,-\pssize)(0.15,-0.15)}
            \rput{\rA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!10](0,0)(0,-\pssize)(-0.15,-0.15)}
        }           
        \multido{\iA=45+90}{4}{
            \rput{\iA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!50](0,0)(0,-0.8\pssize)(0.1,-0.1)}
            \rput{\iA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20](0,0)(0,-0.8\pssize)(-0.1,-0.1)}
        }           
        \multido{\iA=0+90}{4}{
            \rput{\iA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0)(0,-0.8\pssize)(0.1,-0.1)}
            \rput{\iA}(-0.1,0.1){\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0)(0,-0.8\pssize)(-0.1,-0.1)}
        }   
        \uput{1.2\pssize}[14](-0.1;0){\logotextformat ACME Inc} 
        \uput{1.2\pssize}[-10](-0.1;0){\logotextformat A world company that manufactures everything}    
\end{pspicture}}    % put the actual logo

\newcommand{\placelogo}[2]{% \logo{<left>}{<top>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, align=center,]
        \node(logo) at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [anchor=north west] {\logoimg{#1}{#2}};                     
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
% **********************

\begin{document}
    
    \placelogo{2cm}{2cm}    
    
    Some words
    
\end{document}
```

Logo figure inspired in the example "compass" found in [PStricks examples](https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples-list)

**UPDATE** after follow-up question.

The `pspicture` is defined by the command `\logoimg`.

Use `\placelogo{<left>}{<top>}` to position its center in the page.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}   

% ********************** added<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\pssize}\setlength{\pssize}{1cm} % size of the logo image <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\logotextformat}{\sffamily \bfseries \large} % format of the logo text  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\logoimg}[2]{% actual logo
    \begin{pspicture}(#1,-#2)
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.88 0.15 0.11}
        \psset{
            unit=0.7pt,
            linestyle=none,
            fillstyle=solid,
            fillcolor=curcolor
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(74, 18)
            \lineto(56, 18)
            \lineto(56, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \curveto(67, 7)(63, 5)(57, 5)
            \curveto(50, 5)(45, 10)(45, 17)
            \curveto(45, 24)(50, 30)(57, 30)
            \curveto(63, 30)(67, 27)(69, 23)
            \lineto(74, 25)
            \curveto(71, 32)(65, 35)(57, 35)
            \curveto(47, 35)(39, 27)(39, 17)
            \curveto(39, 7)(47, 0)(57, 0)
            \curveto(62, 0)(66, 2)(69, 5)
            \lineto(69, 1)
            \lineto(74, 1)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \closepath
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(27, 61)
            \lineto(5, 61)
            \lineto(5, 75)
            \lineto(0, 75)
            \lineto(0, 42)
            \lineto(5, 42)
            \lineto(5, 56)
            \lineto(27, 56)
            \lineto(27, 42)
            \lineto(33, 42)
            \lineto(33, 75)
            \lineto(27, 75)
            \closepath
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}


\newcommand{\placelogo}[2]{% \logo{<left>}{<top>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, align=center,]
        \node(logo) at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [anchor=north west] {\logoimg{#1}{#2}};                     
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
% **********************

\begin{document}
    
    \placelogo{2cm}{3cm} 
    
    Some words
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried to replicate your code with my logo, but it doesn't work as expected. I have modified the code in my question to include a real use-case example. Here my logo is still bound to the geometry of the page, not to the top left corner of the page. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @nowox Please see the updated answer. Your logo it is fine. Just use `\logoimg` instead of `\logo`  and   `\placelogo{<left>}{<top>}` to position its center in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-abspos,graphicx}

\newcommand\logo[1][]{\pstPutAbs[position=ul](0,0){%
  \tabular{l}\includegraphics[#1]{/tmp/compass}\endtabular
  \sffamily\bfseries\tabular{l}ACME Inc\\A world company that manufactures everything\endtabular}}

\begin{document}
\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin\logo[width=2cm]%
Some words
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) you can place content on the page absolutely. The following adds a key-value option `left` and `top` for the `\logo` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,eso-pic,xkeyval}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names]{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{logokeys}[logokeys@]{left}[0pt]{}% left key (default 0pt)
\define@cmdkey{logokeys}[logokeys@]{top}[0pt]{}% top key (default 0pt)

\newcommand{\logo}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{logokeys}{left,top,#1}%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \hspace*{\logokeys@left}%
      \raisebox{-\logokeys@top}{\raisebox{-\height}{%
        \begin{pspicture}(51.8pt,52.5pt)
          \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.88 0.15 0.11}
          \psset{
            unit=0.7pt,
            linestyle=none,
            fillstyle=solid,
            fillcolor=curcolor
          }
          \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(74, 18)
            \lineto(56, 18)
            \lineto(56, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \curveto(67, 7)(63, 5)(57, 5)
            \curveto(50, 5)(45, 10)(45, 17)
            \curveto(45, 24)(50, 30)(57, 30)
            \curveto(63, 30)(67, 27)(69, 23)
            \lineto(74, 25)
            \curveto(71, 32)(65, 35)(57, 35)
            \curveto(47, 35)(39, 27)(39, 17)
            \curveto(39, 7)(47, 0)(57, 0)
            \curveto(62, 0)(66, 2)(69, 5)
            \lineto(69, 1)
            \lineto(74, 1)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \closepath
          }
          \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(27, 61)
            \lineto(5, 61)
            \lineto(5, 75)
            \lineto(0, 75)
            \lineto(0, 42)
            \lineto(5, 42)
            \lineto(5, 56)
            \lineto(27, 56)
            \lineto(27, 42)
            \lineto(33, 42)
            \lineto(33, 75)
            \lineto(27, 75)
            \closepath
          }
        \end{pspicture}
      }}%
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\logo[left=1cm,top=1cm]

Something

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load textpos with the `[absolute]` option, then positions of textblocks are given with respect to the top-left corner of the page, rather than relative to the location where the textblock would naturally appear.